# sql dynamic columns during select request for categories

Tags: sql, sqlite, dynamic-columns

I have an sql table:

```
date | sum | category
2019-05-01 | 50 | cat1
2019-05-01 | 20 | cat2
2019-05-04 | 1003 | cat2
2019-06-22 | 20 | cat1
```

and so on.

I want to create the following using a select request:

```
date | sum in cat1 | sum in cat2
2019-05-01 | 50 | 20
2019-05-04 | 0 | 1003
2019-06-22  | 20 | 0
```

The categories can't be hardcoded since they are part of the data and can be changed.

You can assume the following:

- category is never null
- exactly one category per transaction
- there can be multiple transactions with the same date and category. sum them.

(Bonus points, if the solution works in sqlite)

Comment: do we know the distinct number of categories?

Comment: @DigvijayS no, I don't know how much there'll be